# A list of modules or classes ( in VB 2010 Express)

Tags: vb.net

I have a set of modules, e.g., itemOne, itemTwo, ... , itemTen, which have similar methods and sub-classes within themselves. I have used "Delegate" and "Enum" to keep track of these methods, and have a systematic way of calling them in a for loop. HOWEVER, I am not sure how to make a collection or array of the modules, with the goal of being able to loop through them.

End goal below, in pseudo code

```
For Num = One to Ten
     With item<Num> % This could be itemOne, or itemTwo, etc. I do NOT know how to do this
          % Call function with the help of for loops. I know how to do this
     End With
End For
```

It would help if there is a way to use a array of strings, and execute them as code during runtime. Something like -- Call String2Code("ItemOne").Something.SomeMethod(), where SomeMethod is a subroutine.

It doesn't necessarily have to be a String2Code type of implementation. In general, I am looking for a way to keep track of an array of "delegates to modules". Of course, "Delegate" only works for Sub/Function in VB, and I have been unable to find a technique to handle modules in a similar fashion. If the address pointers of these modules are stored in an array, I should be able to loop through them.

I will be grateful for any advice. Thank you.

Comment: Reflection http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy.aspx

Comment: @Steve - Will appreciate some further directions, I made a post as an answer. Am I on the right path?

Answer (score 0):

In retrospect this might be simpler.  You should be making them classes in my opinion not modules...

Please note that I have used One, Two, and Three below to represent an object of your different types.

```
Dim col as List(Of Object)
col.add(One)
col.add(Two)
col.add(Three)
For i as integer = 0 to col.Count -1
    If typeof col(i) is [ModuleType1] Then
       CTYPE(col(i), ModuleType1).SubClass.Method()
    Else If TypeOf col(i) is ModuleType2 Then
       CTYPE(col(i), ModuleType2.SubClass2.Method2()
    End If
Next
```

Optionally, you can just make col an array of Objects.

```
Dim col() as Object = {One, Two, Three}
```

Ideally you would avoid using Object and instead all of your modules would use inheritance to group like methods together.  They instead of Object you could use the ParentObject which would maintain the like functionality instead of casting all of the time.

Is this clear as mud?

Steve